# Rails: 404 page not found using Nginx Web Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I am setting up a **Rails 6** Application using **Nginx** Web server and **Puma** Application Server.

I want the **Nginx** web server to serve static web files while the **Puma** Application server will handle dynamic requests.

I have setup **Nginx** and here's my Nginx configuration file for the **Rails 6** application:

```
upstream railsserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {

        # Replace 'localhost' with your FQDN if you want to use
        # your app from remote or if you need to add a certificate 
        server_name localhost;

                root /home/deploy/my-website/public;

        # Define where Nginx should write its logs
        access_log /var/log/nginx/my-website/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/my-website/error.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @railsserver;
        }
       
        location ~ ^/(assets/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
                expires max;
        }

        location @railsserver {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header CLIENT_IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_pass http://railsserver;

                gzip on;
                gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css image/svg+xml application/javas$
                gzip_proxied any;
        }
}
```

I have also restarted Nginx using the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

But each time I try to access the website via a browser, I get the error:

> 404 page not found

I can't seem to figure out where the error is from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The issue was from the **Nginx** configuration file:

**Here's how I solved it**:

Modify this directive:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @railsserver;
```

to this

```
try_files $uri @railsserver;
```

That is remove `$uri/` from the line.

Since we aren't going to be serving any index files (`index.html`) directly, there is no need for it to be present. It causes nginx to try to load the files specified in the index directive, or if none exist, to do a directory index.

And since no index file exists or no index directive exists in our Nginx configuration file due to the Nginx configuration is for a dynamic web application, Nginx returns the error `404 page not found`.

So our configuration will look like this:

```
upstream railsserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {

        # Replace 'localhost' with your FQDN if you want to use
        # your app from remote or if you need to add a certificate 
        server_name localhost;

                root /home/deploy/my-website/public;

        # Define where Nginx should write its logs
        access_log /var/log/nginx/my-website/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/my-website/error.log;

        location / {
                 # First attempt to serve file(s) specified in the index directive,
                 # then the rails application directory
                 try_files $uri @railsserver;
        }
       
        location ~ ^/(assets/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
                expires max;
        }

        location @railsserver {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header CLIENT_IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_pass http://railsserver;

                gzip on;
                gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css image/svg+xml application/javas$
                gzip_proxied any;
        }
}
```

Next, restart Nginx using the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

You can check your website now via your browser, everything should be fine now.

**Resources**: [Does Nginx require an index file for the root directory?](https://serverfault.com/a/558181/544021)

That's all

**I hope this helps**